# Value lookup table in C by strings?

Tags: c

If I have a set of small string values, and I want to fetch a numeric value to represent them, what's the best way to do this via a lookup table?

If I were only needing to do a straight look up, I know the optimal solution would just be a series of if statements:

```
if (strcmp(str, "foo") == 0)
    tmp = FOO;
else if (strcmp(str, "bar") == 0)
    tmp = BAR;
```

But, I ask this because these small string values represent an attribute in a small project I'm writing in C, and the attributes can be read-only or read-write (no write-only for now, maybe never).

So what I currently do just to make sure things work is have a lookup function comprised of an if-then clause like above to look up which values are read-only, and a second functions that looks up which values are read-write.  But this is large and ugly to me.

I'm thinking, have three functions instead.  One function is the lookup function, and it returns an int value that is the numeric form of the string.  But this lookup function can also take a flag that determines whether it fetches a read-only value, or a read-write value.  If a write operation is done on a value that is really read-only, the function will return -EINVAL (or something equivalent).

The other two functions, now still the read and write, just call this lookup function, passing in a string of the value, and the flag that determines whether they're for reading or writing.

Thing is, I don't know how this is modeled in C (if it can be modeled), and searching Google is tiresome with all the content farms ripping this place off (and giving me C++/C# answers instead).

So this is how I think it'll look:

```
int lookup_func(const char *name, const char *flag) {
    int tmpval = 0;

    /* code to do the lookup. */

    if (tmpval == 0)
        return -EINVAL;
    else
        return tmpval;
}

int get_readonly_bit(const char *name) {
    return lookup_func(name, "ro");
}

int get_readwrite_bit(const char *name) {
    return lookup_func(name, "rw")
}
```

Thoughts?  The idea is to reduce code size by not repeating the if-then branches for these two functions, which differ slightly in overall design, and simply let some kind of a lookup function figure out what function this value serves.

Comment: +1 for const-correctness ... *but flag is better as an int (or enum)*

Comment: You want an [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). Depending on your string values it may be as simple as returning the value of the first letter...

Comment: @pmg: there is still a probability of several strings with the same hash. Small, but it is :)

Comment: If the set of strings is fixed **and small**, it is easy to find a minimal perfect hash function.

Comment: @pmg: Yes, I know an int/char is a better flag.  This was quick & dirty example code, though :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you not consider just putting a table in? A hash table is also fine if there are lots of properties.

```
int lookup(const char *name)
{
  typedef struct item_t { const char *name; int writable; int value; } item_t;
  item_t table[] = {
    { "foo", 0, FOO },
    { "bar", 1, BAR },
    { NULL, 0, 0 }
  };
  for (item_t *p = table; p->name != NULL; ++p) {
      if (strcmp(p->name, prop_name) == 0) {
          return p->value;
      }
  }
  return -EINVAL;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. If you are only concerned about "large and ugly" code, this should do, right? If the table is long and your program does a lot of look-ups, I would try to work on that for-loop: e.g. look for a binary-search-implementation that applies to strings and is written in c, of course.

Comment: @AudioDroid: what is large and ugly about it?  It's simple and understandable and quite robust and I've seen it used in many places.  The algorithm is O(n) which might be a problem for long lists.  However, whether it is a problem should be determined with performance analysis, not guesswork.

Comment: I personally discourage this sort of solution for anything but trivial lists.  When using strings in this manner, the issue of locale and case-sensitivity can be problematic.  Furthermore, the efficiency is suspect.  A strcmp implies a sequence of repeated comparisons when one comparison of a hash key would suffice.  When comparing the performance of hashing against a strcmp, the hash method demonstrates better performance for all but trivial lists (in my experience).

Comment: @patthoyts: Sorry, been busy fixing the program up that'll use this.  It's a kernel driver, and a few spinlock deadlocks decided to play hide-and-go-seek.  Per your answer, no I did not.  I'm not familiar with such a construct in C (I'm still a journeyman in C).  I'll give this a run down over the next week and see if I can work it in.  It's not performance critical -- the code in question would be used to access specific I/O registers by things like a script, so speed really won't be a concern (it'll probably remain debug code, too).

Comment: @Throwback1986: locale is not an issue in this, and all the strings being checked are intentionally lowercase.  A hash table would be elegant, but likely very overkill for the code in question.  If you have a sample of a hashcode implementation, post it and I'll give it a go and see how it fits in.

Comment: Worked like a charm with some minor modifications.  Thanks!  (turns out I didn't need the mode bit after all)